# Is it possible to implement a comment section on 'custom' php pages?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking all over but I can't quite phrase what it is that I'm trying to do into a search engine. Here is my question that a human can hopefully answer better.

I have a method of users creating database entries (think of it as creating 'custom avatars') on my website.

What I want to have is a unique page for EACH of these database entries so that I can:

a) Enter in a query into my site's search engine (which I have already developed), and click on the link to the "avatar". This brings me to a page which has all of the information on it which the user entered when they created their avatar, for example:

Name, Age, Favourite Colour

b) Then, sometime in the future I want to be able to have users, when logged in, add comments to these pages, and the comments save.

I would like to know what the best way to go about starting this project would be. I don't want to create html pages for each entry because then they have no functionality.

I was thinking I'd use a general 'view_avatar.php' type page, which loaded information in HTML form using variables and echos from the MySQL database, but I don't know how to tell MySQL to fetch data just off of a user clicking an HTML link.

I figured the guys here would know the best way to do this sort of thing.

Sorry if my question is vague, I just don't know where to start.

Regards!

Comment: if i read it correctly you answered it yourself. You make 1 general template file and fill it with stuff from the database.

Comment: How are users currently authenticating? If they are, they must have some kind of session. What you would do in very general terms is tie their session id to their user id and then use that in your queries. E.g. their entries would have a foreign key to the users table and you'd filter queries with that.

Comment: alright, but lets say theres a link to "John's Avatar"

when I click this link, how do i query the database to retrieve the John's Avatar row, if all I did was click a link? Normally you input data into a field, no?

@thatjuan ... yes they have sessions -- what information does the session_id contain? does it tell me what link they click?

Comment: put some GET parameters on it

Comment: GET parameters on an HTML link? How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For things like this is it good to have a user table in your DB. Each user will have a specific ID that you can look him/her up by. This ID can be used to track users activities around your website. So for example when your user makes a comment, it is stored in a general comments table with their ID attached to it along with the rest of that comments data (content, time, page etc). When you are loading your avatar page, you perform a lookup on the comments table and search for all comments that user made using there unique ID that way you can link the comments in this table back to the user. Regarding how to make that users comments appear once they click a link, have your view_avatar script accept some POST variables. These are appended to the URL so for example

http://www.yourdomain.com/view_avatar.php?id=USERID

When the user clicks that link the view_avatar.php script is run and the id parameter is passed along to it. It is accessible from within that script as $_POST['id']; Using this you can then look up that users comments in a specific SQL table. Read throught this documentation to get a better idea of how it all works in PHP,

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Hope that helps :)

---

edit: sorry gave some bad advise above. the id param will be available as $_GET['id'];
see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for a good explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how I'd do it (very simplified):

Create a file called `user_profile.php`.
When I click on `John's Avatar` I get linked to mysite.com/user_profile.php?id=123(or what ever the id of John is)

The "how i get the query stuff in `user_profile.php` would look something like

```
    <?php
    $user = null;
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'].'"');
    $user = $someUserObject->parseSqlResult(mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }
    if(!is_object($user)) {
        echo 'Sorry no User with id '.$_GET['id']; die;
    }
    ?>
```

Don't get mad at me for not using mysqli, this is just a "how to do it" example